# Cannot install Gnome 3 shell theme

Tags: gnome, themes

I have a theme installed, and I can configure everything using the Gnome Tweak Tool, except for the shell theme. It has an error disabling the option to do this:
[image: here]

I also think that this problem is causing this unattractive GUI glitch, which creates a black box around certain windows such as:

[image: this]

What can I do  to solve this issue?

Comment: Where did you install the theme to? You might need https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/

Comment: I just put it in the .themes dir in my home directory, and selected it from the Tweak Tool

Comment: I also just installed that extension, and it hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: Okay, after rebooting my PC that fix has allowed me to use shell themes, however I still have the 'black box' glitch as shown in the image above.

Comment: Yeah, that glitch seems to be a common problem -  I have had it on occasion, and it comes and goes. Not sure about how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shell Theme option in GNOME Tweak Tool needs the User Shell Themes extension, as the mouse-over pop-up says:
[image]

The extension is available at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/, or by installing `gnome-shell-extensions`:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions
```

If you installed it manually, instead of using the GNOME Shell plugin
(which works on Firefox), then you might need to restart GNOME Shell (press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, type `r`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).